# How to follow all links in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm having trouble clicking all JavaScript based links in a DOM and saving the
output. The links have the form

```
<a id="html" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="goToHtml();">HTML</a>
```

the following code works great:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var fs = require('fs');

var firstUrl = 'http://www.testurl.com/test.html';

var css_selector = '#jan_html';

casper.start(firstUrl);

casper.thenClick(css_selector, function(){
    console.log("whoop");
});

casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.getCurrentUrl() != firstUrl;
}, function then() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
    var file_title = this.getTitle().split(' ').join('_') + '.html';
    fs.write(file_title, this.getPageContent());
});

casper.run();
```

However, how can I get this to work with a selector of "a", clicking all
available links and saving content? I'm not sure how to get the clickWhileSelector to remove nodes from the selector as is done here: [Click on all links matching a selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593449/click-on-all-links-matching-a-selector)

Answer (score 14):

I have this script that first will get all links from a page then save 'href' attributes to an array, then will iterate over this array and then open each link one by one and echo the url :

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel:"verbose",
    debug:true
});
var links;

casper.start('http://localhost:8000');

casper.then(function getLinks(){
     links = this.evaluate(function(){
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
            return link.getAttribute('href');
        });
        return links;
    });
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.each(links,function(self,link){
        self.thenOpen(link,function(a){
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
        });
    });
});
casper.run(function(){
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: How might this be accomplished if you want to be able to add links to the array you are looping through?

Comment: although this is an interesting implementation that can be combined with something [like this](https://coderwall.com/p/uzaaaw/scrape-site-for-js-errors-with-casper-js) to scram errors in a website. i do wonder whether this thing wont stuck in infinite loop..

Answer (score 1):

[rusln's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406293/1816580) works great if all the links have a meaningful `href` attribute (actual URL). If you want to click every `a` that also triggers a javascript function, you may need to iterate some other way over the elements.

I propose using the [XPath generator from stijn de ryck for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178132/1816580).

1. You can then sample all XPaths that are on the page.
2. Then you open the page for every `a` that you have the XPath for and click it by XPath.
3. Wait a little if it is a single page application
4. Do something

```js
var startURL = 'http://localhost:8000',
    xPaths
    x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start(startURL);

casper.then(function getLinks(){
    xPaths = this.evaluate(function(){
        // copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178132/1816580
        function createXPathFromElement(elm) {
            var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
            for (var segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) { 
                if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) { 
                        var uniqueIdCount = 0; 
                        for (var n=0;n < allNodes.length;n++) { 
                            if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute('id') && allNodes[n].id == elm.id) uniqueIdCount++; 
                            if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break; 
                        }; 
                        if ( uniqueIdCount == 1) { 
                            segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")'); 
                            return segs.join('/'); 
                        } else { 
                            segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '"]'); 
                        } 
                } else if (elm.hasAttribute('class')) { 
                    segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]'); 
                } else { 
                    for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) { 
                        if (sib.localName == elm.localName)  i++; }; 
                        segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']'); 
                }; 
            }; 
            return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null; 
        };
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var xPaths = Array.prototype.map.call(links, createXPathFromElement);
        return xPaths;
    });
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.each(xPaths, function(self, xpath){
        self.thenOpen(startURL);
        self.thenClick(x(xpath));
        // waiting some time may be necessary for single page applications
        self.wait(1000);
        self.then(function(a){
            // do something meaningful here
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
        });

        // Uncomment the following line in case each click opens a new page instead of staying at the same page
        //self.back()
    });
});
casper.run(function(){
    this.exit();
});
```