# Click all anchor tags on page with given class, but cancel prior to navigation

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Trying to automate some testing for some analytics tracking code, and I'm running into issues when I try passing `links` into the `each()` method.

I copied a lot of this from [stackoverflow - how to follow all links in casperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406293/387254), but I don't need return the `href` of the link; I need to return the link itself (so I can click it). I keep getting this `error: each() only works with arrays.` Am I not returning an array?

**UPDATE:**

For each anchor tag that has .myClass, click it, then return requested parameters from `casper.options.onResourceReceived` e.g. event category, event action, etc. I may or may not have to cancel the navigation the happens after the click; I simply only need to review the request, and do not need the follow page to load.

Testing steps:

1. click link that has `.myClass`
2. look at request parameters
3. cancel the click to prevent it from going to the next page.

I'm new to javascript and casper.js, so I apologize if I'm misinterpreting.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**
I've updated the code to instead return an array of classes. There are a few sketchy bits of code in this though (see comments inline).

However, I'm now having issues canceling the navigation after the click. .Clear() canceled all js. Anyway to prevent default action happening after click? Like `e.preventDefault();`?

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casper.options.onResourceReceived = function(arg1, response) {

    if (response.url.indexOf('t=event') > -1) {
        var query = decodeURI(response.url);
        var data = query.split('&');
        var result = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var item = data[i].split('=');
            result[item[0]] = item[1];
        }
        console.log('EVENT CATEGORY = ' + result.ec + '\n' +
            'EVENT ACTION = ' + result.ea + '\n' +
            'EVENT LABEL = ' + decodeURIComponent(result.el) + '\n' +
            'REQUEST STATUS = ' + response.status
        );

    }
};

var links;
//var myClass = '.myClass';

casper.start('http://www.leupold.com', function getLinks() {
    links = this.evaluate(function() {

        var links = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
        // having issues when I attempted to pass in myClass var.

        links = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link) {

            // seems like a sketchy way to get a class. what happens if there are multiple classes?
            return link.getAttribute('class');
        });

        return links;
    });
});

casper.waitForSelector('.myClass', function() {

    this.echo('selector is here');
    //this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    //this.echo(JSON.stringify(links));

    this.each(links, function(self, link) {
        self.echo('this is a class : ' + link);
        // again this is horrible
        self.click('.' + link);
    });
});



casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: You cannot return DOM elements from the page context.

Comment: What does `this.echo(JSON.stringify(links));` print before `this.each`? I suspect it's an array with a lot of `undefined`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yep, it's an array with a lot of `undefined`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. just realized that I should be returning an array of classes to pass into the each, to then pass into my click().

Comment: Sort of, still working on canceling the default action after the click. I've updated the code above with my new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems that you're dealing with.

## 1. Select elements based on class

Usually a class is used multiple times. So when you first select elements based on this class, you will get elements that have that class, but it is not guaranteed that this will be unique. See for example this selection of element that you may select by `.myClass`:

1. `myClass`
2. `myClass myClass2`
3. `myClass myClass3`
4. `myClass`
5. `myClass myClass3`

When you later iterate over those class names, you've got a problem, because 4 and 5 can never be clicked using `casper.click("." + links[i].replace(" ", "."))` (you need to additionally replace spaces with dots). `casper.click` only clicks the first occurrence of the specific selector. That is why [I used `createXPathFromElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24451332/1816580) taken from [stijn de ryck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178132/1816580) to find the unique XPath expression for every element inside the page context.

You can then click the correct element via the unique XPath like this

```
casper.click(x(xpathFromPageContext[i]));
```

## 2. Cancelling navigation

This may depend on what your page actually is.

*Note:* I use the `casper.test` property which is the [Tester module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html). You get access to it by invoking casper like this: `casperjs test script.js`.

*Note:* There is also the [`casper.waitForResource`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource) function. Have a look at it.

### 2.1 Web 1.0

When a click means a new page will be loaded, you may add an event handler to the [`page.resource.requested`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-requested) event. You can then `abort()` the `request` without resetting the page back to the `startURL`.

```
var resourceAborted = false;
casper.on('page.resource.requested', function(requestData, request){
    if (requestData.url.match(/someURLMatching/)) {
        // you can also check requestData.headers which is an array of objects:
        // [{name: "header name", value: "some value"}]
        casper.test.pass("resource passed");
    } else {
        casper.test.fail("resource failed");
    }
    if (requestData.url != startURL) {
        request.abort();
    }
    resourceAborted = true;
});
```

and in the test flow:

```
casper.each(links, function(self, link){
    self.thenClick(x(link));
    self.waitFor(function check(){
        return resourceAborted;
    });
    self.then(function(){
        resourceAborted = false; // reset state
    });
});
```

### 2.2 Single page application

There may be so many event handlers attached, that it is quite hard to prevent them all. An easier way (at least for me) is to

1. get all the unique element paths,
2. iterate over the list and do every time the following:

   1. Open the original page again (basically a reset for every link)
   2. do the click on the current XPath

This is basically what I do in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24451332/1816580).

Since single page apps don't load pages. The [`navigation.requested`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#navigation-requested) and [`page.resource.requested`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-requested) will not be triggered. You need the [`resource.requested`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-requested) event if you want to check some API call:

```
var clickPassed = -1;
casper.on('resource.requested', function(requestData, request){
    if (requestData.url.match(/someURLMatching/)) {
        // you can also check requestData.headers which is an array of objects:
        // [{name: "header name", value: "some value"}]
        clickPassed = true;
    } else {
        clickPassed = false;
    }
});
```

and in the test flow:

```
casper.each(links, function(self, link){
    self.thenOpen(startURL);
    self.thenClick(x(link));
    self.waitFor(function check(){
        return clickPassed !== -1;
    }, function then(){
        casper.test.assert(clickPassed);
        clickPassed = -1;
    }, function onTimeout(){
        casper.test.fail("Resource timeout");
    });
});
```

Comment: Freakin' awesome man! This is great. Let me take a look at this this weekend, and digest. Much appreciated!