# CasperJS Click on all links matching a selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs, selectors-api

I have read this [question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593449/click-on-all-links-matching-a-selector), and wish to take it a little bit further.

I want to use [CasperJS.click(selector)](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#click) function to click multiple links matching a selector. Please note that the links do not have a significant `href` tag.

Consider the following markup:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <h1 class='myLink'>Cocacola</h1>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1 class='myLink'>Sprite</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The answers I've mentioned on top here suggest deleting the links so we can click the remaining elements with `casper.exists` and so on. What if I don't want to manipulate the page?

For reasons beyond my conception, using:

```
document.querySelector("div .myLink:nth-of-type(1)");
```

catches the first `h1`, Cocacola. But:

```
document.querySelector("div .myLink:nth-of-type(2)");
```

returns `null`.

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ny759/).

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click all anchor tags on page with given class, but cancel prior to navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603365/click-all-anchor-tags-on-page-with-given-class-but-cancel-prior-to-navigation)

Comment: If you don't expect that a new page is loaded then you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24451332/1816580).

Comment: `nth-of-type` operates only on element types, `h1` in this case. It will not take the class `.myLink` into account. The index only means something for elements directly under the same parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the reason `:nth-of-type(1)` works but `:nth-of-type(2)` doesn't is because there is only exactly one `h1` of each type as a child of its parent `div`. The class selector `.myLink` is a separate condition entirely and does not affect how `:nth-of-type()` works.

The reason your first statement appears to return the first element, even though there are technically *two* elements matching `:nth-of-type(1)`, is because [`querySelector()` returns only the first match](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector).

To obtain the first and second elements matching your selector, use `querySelectorAll()` instead of `querySelector()`, and an indexer instead of the `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class:

```
var cocacola = document.querySelectorAll("div .myLink")[0];
var sprite = document.querySelectorAll("div .myLink")[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS spec for [:nth-of-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) says that:

> The :nth-of-type(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same expanded element name before it in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of n, and has a parent element.

That is, the elements will have to be siblings.

For example,

```
<div>
  <h1 class='myLink'>Cocacola</h1>
  <h1 class='myLink'>Miranda</h1>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1 class='myLink'>Sprite</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The selector `div .myLink:nth-of-type(2)` will select Miranda.  That is, given n siblings of type 'div .myLink', the selector will select the second element from them.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UY4Qy/) for the above example.

Hope this helps!